# How to debug the ELF loading process on Linux (Fedora)?

Tags: linux, debugging, linker, executable, elf

What are some effective approaches to debug the actual process of loading an ELF binary on a Linux system? I am on Fedora 36 and have created an ELF file. However, when I try to run the ELF file from bash by entering `./myElfFile`, I get an error like `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`. What I am trying to determine is **WHICH specific exec format error**, and I'd like to do this using a debugger or some other dynamic tracing. I once had to do this on Windows and I ended up using WinDbg in kernel debug mode, and something called GFlags, and I turned on "loader snaps" which allowed me to watch the entire portable executable loading process. Eventually, I found the checks inside of `NtCreateSection` and its callees. How would I do something like this in the Linux/ELF world? I want to find out at which step of the loading process it is failing, and precisely which check fails.

Comment: What happens when you do `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./myElfFile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I am trying to determine is WHICH specific exec format error, and I'd like to do this using a debugger or some other dynamic tracing.

The problem (invalid `ELF` file) is most likely detected by the *kernel*. Because of that, your program never starts up, and no debugger or any other *user-space* tool will help.

There are a few approaches you can try:

- If `myElfFile` started as valid file and was modified / patched, examine differences between the output from `readelf -l ...` on the working and non-working copies, and see if you can spot a violation of some required invariants (e.g. does `.p_offset % pagesize == .p_vaddr % pagesize` ?).
- Use `readelf -a myElfFile` and see if `readelf` prints any warnings. If it does, you can debug `readelf` to figure out what it's complaining about -- it may or may not be the same thing which causes the kernel to reject your binary as well.
- Update your question with the output from `readelf -l myElfFile` and hope that someone else points out what's wrong with it.
- Use [user-mode Linux](https://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/) to debug the kernel *while it is trying to `exec` the file*.